# How to do it with views?

Tags: 7, views

I have two content types
BLOG and PROPERTIES

In BLOG, I have an entity reference field called "Related properties" that will point to the PROPERTIES content type.

Every BLOG node is gonna have a unique set of entity reference values i.e Content/Contents of PROPERTIES content type.

Now what I want is to list the entity referenced contents of content type PROPERTIES in a view with respect to the nid of the content of type BLOG.

How can I do this using Views?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view of type content

Then add contextual filter "Content: Nid". Here you can add different settings depending on your needs.

Under "Relationships" you should be able to select the entity reference field. This brings in all information about the referenced properties.

As fields you can now add any field from the references properties - just add this relationship